# cURL -F tag equivalent in PHP

Tags: php, curl, mailgun

I have this CURL request and I need to convert it to PHP script. 
I am not able to understand how to convert the "-F address='bob@example.com'" part.

```
curl -s --user 'api:API_KEY' \
    https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/bounces \
    -F address='bob@example.com'
```

Without the '-F' thing, it looks like

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/bounces");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "api" . ":" . "API_KEY");

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

It would be really great if someone can help me with this.

Thanks!

Comment: Ditch the GET and use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $assoc_array_of_fields);`

Comment: Run `man curl` and then scroll until you find what `-F` is, then mosey on over to the [relevant docs](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to figure out how to replicate it.

Comment: That worked @Scuzzy, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is a similar problem such as `--data (-d)`, `--form (-F)`, and `--data-urlencode`.

This can be found in the form `enctype` (`Content-Type`) of the HTML.
PHP-CURL does not have this, so `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` is used instead.

But, You need to make it clear under the following conditions.

- --form (-F): `multipart/form-data`
- --data (-d): none (auto)
- --data-urlencode: `application/x-www-urlencoeded`

You can send the data with the `Content-Type` header.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/gnh1201/reasonableframework/blob/5abc5b2a4cb7fd64f2f66a457f9051edeaceb28a/helper/webpagetool.php#L100